# Поиск пиковх значений

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Есть массив из 200 элементов. Необходимо найти пиковые значения.

Для примера:

> 1,2,3,4,5,5,4,6,7,8,5,17,40,5,4,3,2,1...-
> надо взять число 40, а не какое-то другое.

P.S.
На практике - это амплитудно-частотная характеристика

Comment: Ну так это же простой поиск максимума?! Или я не прав?

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, почему только 40, а не 8 и 40 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static bool IsPeak(this int[] array, int index)
{
    if (array.length < 3)
        return false; //если элементов всего 2, то о пиках речь не идет
    if (index == 0) //левый край
        return array[0] > array[1];
    else if (index == array.length - 1) //правый край
        return array[array.length - 2] < array[array.length - 1];
    else //где-то в середине
        return array[index] > array[index + 1] && array[index] > array[index - 1]

}

static int[] GetPeaks(this int[] src)
{
    src.Select((x,i)=>new {val = x, index = i}).Where(x => src.IsPeak(x.i).Select(x=>x.val).ToArray();
}

//usage
var peaks = src.GetPeaks();
```

Comment: Каюсь, написал на шарпе, но на плюсах алгоритм тот же, разве что будет не так изящно в плане синтаксиса

Answer (score 0):

```
struct extrem {
int maxval;
int minval;
};

struct extrem getExtr(int *acx, int n)
{
int index = 0;
struct extrem ex;
    ex.maxval = acx[index];
    ex.minval = maxval;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
    if (acx[i] > ex.maxval)
    ex.maxval = acx[i];
    if (acx[i] < ex.minval)
    ex.minval = acx[i];
    }
    return ex;
    }
```

Comment: Пиковых значений может быть несколько(до 10)

Comment: тогда нужен критерий что считать пиковым значением :)